# Can't print contents of list, it prints Namesspace and Classname instead

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach, printing

Im adding either cars or trucks to a list, by user input. Later I want to print these to a RichTextBox, the thing is it prints the Namespance and class name instead of the actual contents. My code as follows:

```
Vehicle v0 = new Car(vehicleTypeString, textBoxPlate.Text, 
textBoxMake.Text, textBoxColour.Text, DateTime.Now, 
Car.parkingSpotInput); // These are just user input
vehicles.Add(v0);

foreach (Vehicle v in vehicles)
{
    if (v is Car)
    {
        richTextBoxCar.Text = v.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBoxTruck.Text = v.ToString();
    }
}
```

This might look like a duplicate but all the other question and their
respective answers did not seem to help.

Comment: You’re calling  ToString on an object instance. Try using Vehichles property instead. Like v.Name

Comment: What is the actual content? You need to override ToString() method in class to return whatever you want you want. The default ToString() method returns only namespace and class name

Comment: Since you are doing v.ToString(), it prints namespace and classname, try `v.VehicleType.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks guys, the v.Name and v.VehicleType.ToString() variations did the trick, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override `ToString()` method of your class. Something  like:

```
public class Car
{
    private string VehicleType;
    private string BoxPlate;
    private string BoxColour;
    private string BoxMake;
    private DateTime CreationTime;
    private string ParkingSpotInput;

    public Car(string vehicleType, string boxPlate, string boxMake, string boxColour, DateTime creationTime, string parkingSpot)
    {
        this.VehicleType = vehicleType;
        this.BoxPlate = boxPlate;
        this.BoxColour = boxColour;
        this.CreationTime = creationTime;
        this.ParkingSpotInput = parkingSpot;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"VehicleType: {this.VehicleType}, BoxPlate: {this.BoxPlate}, BoxColour: {this.BoxColour}");
    }
}
```

Sure, you decide yourself, what exactly you want to output in `ToString` method.

and similar `ToString` implementation for your `Truck` class too.